# How can I restore Mathematica icons?

Tags: notebooks

Please, how can I restore Mathematica icons?
I pressed some buttons and all Mathematica icons (top) and Windows icons (bottom)
disappeared.

Thank you,

Marian

Comment: What buttons, what are Mathematica icons and Windows icons? Unless you provide a screenshot or a more detailed description I am afraid we can't help you.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I do not remember what buttons I pressed. I worked something in Matematica. Now the screen in Mathematica covers all the icons.

Comment: So I have no access to any icon. Thank you

Comment: I guess it was `F12`. Hit it again.

Comment: Yes, great! Thank you! Marian

Comment: On a Mac to toggle `Full Screen` use `command + option + f` or the `Full Screen` menu item under the `Window` menu.

Comment: Note that one can also toggle full screen from the right-click menu, at least in Windows.  This is useful since the `Window` and other menus are hidden in full screen mode.